# Python - Placing a string that looks like json on a remote server but quotes are being stripped

Tags: python

I am placing a file on a remote machine using paramiko ssh as follows.

```
rl = str(""" {"run_list":["role[monitor_server]"]}""")
cmd = """sudo touch /etc/chef/first-boot.json;sudo su - -c 'echo "%s" >> /etc/chef/first-boot.json'""" % (rl)
ssh.exec_command(cmd)
```

However, when I look at the file it looks like this.

```
{run_list:[role[monitor_server]]}
```

I need it to to look this this:
   {"run_list":["role[monitor_server]"]}

How to I keep the quotes?

Comment: Try to use single quotes

Comment: Tried that.  Using single quotes does not help

Comment: Do you have logs for the remote machine? Can you see the command that actually gets run? Also, have you considered creating a file locally and transferring it with SFTP or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes would need to be escaped once to fit in the argument to the `echo` command. This is double-quote-delimited ‘weak escaping’: every `"` would have to be escaped to `\"` and you would also have to worry about `\`, `$` and `` ` ``. The results are then dropped into the argument to the `su` command, in single-quote-delimited ‘strong escaping’. Here, any single quote characters have to be included by breaking out of the string, eg by replacing with `'\''`.

Nested escaping is tricky to get right, and given `su` is involved the consequences of any mistake would appear to be dire for security. Avoid nested templating, and templating shell commands, at all costs.

A potentially better solution would be to `cat > /etc/chef/first-boot.json` and then pipe in the contents you want stored through the `stdin` file-like object that `exec_command` returns. No need to worry about escaping then.

Or simply use Paramiko's SFTPClient to transfer the file.

(Also, `str()` on the first line is completely redundant.)

Comment: I used sftp to transfer the file. Command line what getting messy

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping quotes. This is specific solution but should work.

```
>>> rl = """ {"run_list":["role[monitor_server]"]}""".replace('"', '\\"')
>>> print """sudo touch /etc/chef/first-boot.json;sudo su - -c 'echo "%s" >> /etc/chef/first-boot.json'""" % (rl)
sudo touch /etc/chef/first-boot.json;sudo su - -c 'echo " {\"run_list\":[\"role[monitor_server]\"]}" >> /etc/chef/first-boot.json'
```